# how i change my fontSize. when screen Size change?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I want to create a multi platform application whose support all type of window size.
But when my window height or width change than my fontSize is not change.
i want to change its size with percentage of height or width. 
how i can do?

plz Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is too easy.

First you check your window height or width size

```
var curHeight = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;
var curWidth = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;
```

and then set with your requirement.

```
font:{fontSize = Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth*25/100},
```

or

```
font : {fontSize = curWidth*25/100},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. earlier contact u